# "No provider for" in my Angular 2.0.0 project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have created a simple service called SecurityService.  This is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SecurityService {
    items: any[];

    constructor() {
        this.items = [
            { name: 'User 1' },
            { name: 'User 2' },
            { name: 'User 3' }
        ];
    }

    getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

And in order to utilize this service I have created a simple page.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SecurityService } from '../services/security.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'test-page',
    template: require('./test/test.page.html'),
    providers: [SecurityService]
})
export class TestPage {
    items: any[];

    constructor(private securitySvc: SecurityService) {
          this.items = securitySvc.getItems();
    }
}
```

When I load this page, I receive the error that "No provider is given for SecurityService!".  After a lot of searching I wasn't able to figure out the resolution to this problem.

Should I post anything else to help resolve this issue.

All help is greatly appreciated.

- sroye98

Comment: Provided code is perfectly valid, try to rebuild application, restart ng serve.

Comment: Could it be that SecurityService somehow gets instantiated before the given 'test-page' Component?

Comment: For test purpose, try to provide SecurityService in AppModule instead of TestPage

Comment: you need to declare your service at your module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly happened, but as soon as I rebuilt the application within Visual Studio 2015.  The application start to work.  As kemsky said the code is good, probably something wonky with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what you show, the services also have to be registered at module level:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { ConfigurationService } from './services/configuration.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [  
    //...
  ],
  providers: [
    ConfigurationService
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```